# How to transfer data in layer using MVC and 3 tier architecture?

Tags: java, design-patterns, web-applications

As design-pattern if i am correct we use strings ( normally called business logic status ) to convey the message between layers. But my problem is if a method return string then how to transfer other data objects . For this situation i am currently using http request object (which is global) to transfer data, which makes all the 3 layers dependent on presentation layer so it  is not good.

Is there any other way to transfer data between layers?

Answer (score 1):

Passing messages around using strings is considered a bad idea (google "Stringly typed") and definitely not a design pattern. You should create proper objects and pass them between the layers.

Comment: No, actually that is not my mean. I am using string like struts uses , where each string tells which page to be shown. I am not transferring any data using string , this string here is just as status of last method call like : device added, error occurred , already exist etc..

I am transferring data using request object (which is global)